# Implementing IPermission

Tags: c#, .net, permissions

I'm considering writing a custom `IPermission` implementation but am not clear as to how it should work. I've already implemented `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`. What I would like to accomplish is to be able to check permissions vis a vis the current `IPrincipal`'s authorizations rather than its roles. Generally, authorizations are read/add-delete/update/none for a given type. So I would like to write something like this:

```
[CustomPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Type = typeof(Foo), MinimumAuthorization = AuthorizationFlags.Read)]
public void SomeMethod(){}
```

Is this possible? I've looked over the code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.ipermission.aspx. This shows how to implement the interface, but I don't understand how the above pseudo-code would be able to check against the `IPrincipal`'s authorizations for the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomPermission` implementation of [IPermission.Demand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.ipermission.demand.aspx) should be able to look at the [Thread.Current.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx), cast that to your custom principal and from there investigate your authorization data.

Comment: Ah yes. The Demand method was not implemented in any of the msdn examples, so I wasn't even aware of it. Thanks!