# Is there a method such as "IPermission.TryDemand"?

Tags: c#, .net

The current implementation of `IPermission` doesn't make sense to me, if I wanted to perform an operation that could potentially throw a `SecurityException`, then why would I call `IPermission.Demand` to cause just that?

I am actually using the method `IPermission.Demand` to modify the flow of my program, which seems like the most sensible use to me, I don't need it to throw an exception, so is there a similar method that returns a `bool`?

Comment: No, alas. You can decompile it yourself to see: it's in mscorlib.

Comment: No, its a published interface and contains no such method, additionally the expectation is for Demand to throw if the requirement is not met.

Comment: [StackOverFlow Previouis Posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498787/implementing-ipermission)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I'm not looking to implement `IPermission`, I actually need the given method in `ReflectionPermission`.

Comment: @DJKRAZE that question is about implementing an IPermission, this question is about using the interface in other code.

Comment: @Rup - Too bad, but no matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a feature like that as far as I know - you can implement it as an extension method that wraps `Demand`, something like this:

```
public static class IPermissionExtensions
{
    public static bool TryDemand(this IPermission permission)
    {
        try
        {
            permission.Demand();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
if (somePermission.TryDemand())
{
    // ...
}
```

The only problem with this method is that catching exceptions can be slow, especially if you're demanding permissions all the time in your code.

The solution to that would be to pre-load all the security demands at once when your application is launched and store the results for later lookup. Something similar to this:

```
public class PermissionManager
{
    private Dictionary<IPermission, bool> permissions;

    public PermissionManager(IEnumerable<IPermission> permissions)
    {
        foreach (var permission in permissions)
        {
            this.permissions.Add(permission, permission.TryDemand());
        }
    }

    public bool HasPermission(IPermission permission)
    {
        bool value;
        if (permissions.TryGetValue(permission, out value))
            return value;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the overhead of exception throwing is exactly my problem.